# Oracle Database 10g Express Edition AND Date Formats

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, ora-01843

I'm new to Oracle (I've been using MySQL mainly until now) so this might be a dumb question. But I have created this table (names are not english but ignore that, that is not important):

```
CREATE TABLE Auta (
id_auto NUMBER(5) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
typ CHAR(10),
specifikacia_typu CHAR(15),
SPZ CHAR(8),
farba CHAR(20),
datum_vyroby DATE,
pocet_miest NUMBER(2),
pociatok_km NUMBER(6),
poplatok_denny NUMBER(4),
poplatok_km NUMBER(2));
```

Then I tried using this INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO Auta VALUES (
1
,'Audi'
,'A6'
,'KE1-1548'
,'cierna'
,'20-12-2004'
,5
,158749
,1356
,88
);
```

And I get an error:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

The date format I am using is DD-MM-YYYY. I also tried DD.MM.YYYY, DD/MM/YYYY, I also tried switching month and day like this - MM-DD-YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY - and still the same error.

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
,'20-12-2004'
```

...with:

```
, TO_DATE('20-12-2004', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Reference: [TO_DATE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Answer (score 0):

oracle date format is DD-MON-YY .

Answer (score 0):

Use date format of `20-april-2004` instead of `20-4-2004`.

Comment: Here on SO we prefer answers where you explain WHY you are saying what you are saying. Perhaps add some text to your answer so the OP understands your suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **DD-MMM-YYYY** format while inserting date into the database.

For example, `15-Mar-2013`.

Comment: This is not a proper answer. It does not have any insight to the technical problem at hand.